He instalado SFML en Code::Blocks y no puedo ejecutar mi programa
He instalado SFML-2.6.1 en Code::Blocks 20.03, pero al momento de ejecutar mi programa me da el siguiente error:

No se encuentra el punto de entrada del procedimiento _ZSt28_throw_bad_array_new_lengthv en la biblioteca de vínculos dinámicos.

No se como solucionar el error y no quiero reinstalar el sistema operativo. Mi pc ejecuta Windows 11

Este es el error? Si lo copias bien podemos darnos cuenta que no puede encontrar un DLL. Como podrás ver en las respuestas a esa pregunta, basta con copiar los DLL a la carpeta de trabajo o agregar la ruta de los DLL al path

Ya he copiado las DLL a la carpeta done esta el ejecutable y sigue marcando error. al parecer el error es con las librerías: sfml-graphics-2.dll y sfml-window-2.dll

Publicaste en el area de respuestas pero eso no responde a tu pregunta. Considera usar los comentarios para eso. Mira de nuevo el link que compartí, claramente dice que el problema está en las librerías de MinGW, libstdc++-6.dll
